# Have there been any advances in space exploration due to COVID-19 and/or shelter-in-place behavior?

Tags: planning, emergency, international-politics, amateur-radio

Complementing [Have there been any setbacks due to COVID-19— like delays or data-loss?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43253/12102) I'm asking if there have been any advances or benefits due to COVID-19 and the "shelter in place" behavior it has required. Answers might include things like finding new ways to work spaceflight jobs from home, use of spaceflight resources and know-how for public health, or having extra time to pursue "when I get a round tuit" projects.